# I want to reorder sections of lines in text file with Python

Tags: python

Ive got a shell file I'm opening as a text file with update commands, like this :

```
set line dnsConfig domain gggg.domain.com 
set line dnsConfig address 9.9.9.9
set line dnsConfig isUp true
set line dnsConfig parameterAlpha 133

...
```

I want to reorder this like so:

```
set line dnsConfig isUp true
set line dnsConfig parameterAlpha 133
set line dnsConfig domain gggg.domain.com 
set line dnsConfig address 9.9.9.9
...
```

This is just an illustration of my file(not a good one, I know), but I want to reorder only those items. I have experimented with Python's `readlines()` and looping through that way with set string parameters, but am stuck on how to move forward with this.

Comment: What do you want to order them by? Or do you want to manually reorder them?

Comment: So manually reordering them is really the only way I can think of to produce the desired affect I want. So manually changing the 'groups' of these configs to the order I want. Each group having the four lines from the shell that is.

Comment: You mean you always want the top four lines to be reordered in the order 3, 4, 1, 2?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should reorder accordingly and leave the subsequent lines intact:

```
fname = 'test.txt'
new_lines = list()
with open(fname, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    new_lines = lines

tmp = new_lines[0:4]
new_lines[0], new_lines[1] = tmp[2], tmp[3]
new_lines[2], new_lines[3] = tmp[0], tmp[1]

with open('out.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    for line in new_lines:
        new_file.write(line + '\n')
```

Get the lines from the file, reorder the ones you want, and write to the destination file -- which should produce:

```
set line dnsConfig isUp true
set line dnsConfig parameterAlpha 133
set line dnsConfig domain gggg.domain.com
set line dnsConfig address 9.9.9.9
another line
and another
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need. Thank you very much.